# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource []: Java heap space

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an application that uses spring-boot version 2.6.4 and the entities uses `javax.persistence` API, but I need to add this DataTables dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But this cannot work with that version of Spring, so I upgraded to 3.1.2 and used the `jakarta.persistence` API instead of the of the `javax.persistence` API and now the application won't start and it takes about 40 minutes to throw the following exception"

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-15T11:56:25.431-04:00 ERROR 6052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at com.aegis.kyc.KycApplication.main(KycApplication.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:342) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:313) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.equals(AbstractList.java:545) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.AssociationKey.equals(AssociationKey.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.removeNode(HashMap.java:826) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.remove(HashMap.java:805) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.remove(HashSet.java:245) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.removeVisitedAssociationKey(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.withRegisteredAssociationKeys(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1233) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.FetchParent.generateFetchableFetch(FetchParent.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$createFetchableBiConsumer$7(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:846) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$986/0x000001d09f7b5d10.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.visitFetches(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:684) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$979/0x000001d09f7afd68.visitFetches(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.visitFetches(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.afterInitialize(AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.<init>(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.lambda$generateFetch$0(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1258) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping$$Lambda$991/0x000001d09f7bc228.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.withRegisteredAssociationKeys(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1233) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.FetchParent.generateFetchableFetch(FetchParent.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$createFetchableBiConsumer$7(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:846) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$986/0x000001d09f7b5d10.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.visitFetches(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:684) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$979/0x000001d09f7afd68.visitFetches(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.visitFetches(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note that my entities were annotated with `@Audited` and that threw another XML type exception so I commented it out and now I get the error above.

Comment: The fact that it's taking forty minutes to run out of heap indicates that you have enough memory; the fact that you're running out of heap suggests some circular reference.  I recommend attaching VisualVM to the process when you start it up; it will give you an indication of what is filling up the heap to help you hone in on the problem.